# CSS positioning breaks mouse events

Tags: html, css

**[I made a barebones example of this here.](http://jsfiddle.net/uW9jk/2/)**

What causes this?  By just applying a z-index to a div (in the example, `.spread`), mouse events are completely gone.  In the plugin I'm working on, I *need* to use z-index for positioning, and I'd rather not make the user using my plugin try to work around this themselves in the future.

Basically, by simply applying

```
position:relative;
z-index:*anything less than 0)
```

Any and all mouse events will be nulled.  Even if I try to add a positive z-index to just the `a`s, it still doesn't work.

How can I fix this so I can put negative z-indexes on divs while still allowing the contents of them to be clickable/hoverable/whateverable?

**Edit:**  Well I'm dumb.  I didn't know `body` had it's own z-index, I just figured it'd be under everything (because why would you want anything beneath the entire page, just display:none it) Thanks everyone!

Comment: Set the contents inside of them to a higher z-index? It sounds like your problem is that your div z-index is below the document z-index. That should never happen.

Comment: @crush I tried that, it still doesn't work.  Edit: Ah, maybe.  I'll check!  Edit: nope :(

Comment: Why is it imperative that you use negative `z-index`? Just set everything else to a higher `z-index` that is positive.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uW9jk/4/ If you set the z-index on the `body` to be lower than the `z-index` on the `.spread` element, then you can click them again...

Comment: you have 10,000 values that u can work with in the positive range of `z-index`. i'm sure you can find a way to make it work keeping everything positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a negative `z-index` positions the element behind the document's `<body>`.

Try this instead:

```
.spread { z-index: 1; }    
header  { z-index: 2; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uW9jk/3/

Comment: Yeeep, that seems to be the problem.  I don't suppose I can set the body's z-index to something extremely negative?  It's really hacky, but if it does the trick...  I'll accept when I can in 10 minutes!  Thanks!

Comment: @Jaxo yes you can set the BODY to something very negative. The question is do you need too.

Comment: Pretty much, my plugin calculates z-indexes relative to what the user enters in a `data-layer` attribute, and if the user wants a negative value, a negative value is what they shall get.  I wouldn't do this myself in practice, but I'm finding a negative value with my plugin produces a very cool effect.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use negative z-indexes. Changing the `-2` in your example to a `0` or a `1` or anything else positive fixed the problem. [Proof.](http://jsfiddle.net/ue3GJ/)

Answer (score 1):

By setting a negative `z-index` your `div` element will be behind the `body` element, which by default have `z-index: 0`

This is confirmed by setting the z-index of the body. http://jsfiddle.net/uW9jk/5/

```
body{
    z-index: -3;
    position: relative;
}
```

---

Accordingly to [docs.webplatform](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/z-index)

> **Positive z-index values are positioned above a negative** (or lesser value) z-index. Two objects with the same z-index are stacked
>   according to source order. A positive value positions the element
>   above text that has no defined z-index, and a negative value positions
>   it below. Set this parameter to null to remove the attribute. The
>   z-index property only applies to objects that have the position
>   property set to relative or absolute. The property does not apply to
>   windowed controls, such as select objects. **Input from pointing
>   devices, such as a mouse, does not penetrate through overlapping
>   elements** even if the elements are not visible. **This is also true for
>   positioned elements with a negative z-index** unless:
>
> The parent is a scrolling container (that is, its overflow property is
>   set to auto or scroll). The parent is positioned (that is, its
>   position property is set to absolute, relative, or fixed).

**Correction:** the `body` element have `z-index: auto` by default, but make sense to interpret `auto` being a `0` or `positive index` since everything below 0 will be behind it.

---

**Note:** Negative z-index values are CSS2.1 behavior, not allowed in CSS2 and earlier.

```
Negative z-index Support: Webkit 1.0 | Gecko(FF) 3.0 | IE 4.0 | Opera 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know body had a default z-index of 0, but it makes sense now...  Major "d'oh" moment.